# PHP array_push to multi-dimensional array using array as path

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Let's say that we want to add new data (`$newData`) to an multi-dimensional array (`$array`) using an other array as path (`$path`) that can be of any size.

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'), true);
$path = [0,1,1]; # or bigger
...
array_push($array[0]['children'][1]['children'][1]['children'], $newData);
file_put_contents('data.json', json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

How to translate

```
$path = [0,1,1]; # or bigger
```

to the corresponding

```
array_push($array[0]['children'][1]['children'][1]['children'], $newData);
```

Comment: Since I was already in the midst of doing it:
`function setDeep(&$le_array, $path, $value) {
    $tempArr = &$le_array;
    foreach($path as $key) {
  $tempArr = &$tempArr[$key]['children'];
    }
    array_push($tempArr,$value);
}
setDeep($array, [0,1,1], 'hello');`

Comment: super nice thank you!